# Stomp.framework iPhone linking. Anyone have experience?

Tags: iphone, linker, stomp

Having trouble linking the Stomp.framework into an iPhone SDK application.

http://code.google.com/p/stompframework/

I follow the instructions, adding it to the project, adding a Build Phase for Copying the Files, and including it via #import .

I keep getting "image not found".

Anyone try this and/or have a clear idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iPhone SDK doesn't support embedding frameworks in applications. I believe it supports dylibs, though I'm not certain of that fact. However, the safest thing to do would be to take the source of that framework and compile it directly into your application.

Comment: I think you are correct, and that it will need to be a static library. Will try and cook up my own stomp lib and see what I come up with.

Answer (score 1):

This may be better:

http://github.com/juretta/objc-stomp

I found it fairly easy to get going.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that whatever folder contains the .framework bundle is listed in the Framework Search Paths setting of your target or project.

There's more you'd need to do if you want to embed the framework in your application but that's another question.

*edit:* Totally ignored the iPhone requirement there, you'll have to compile the framework as a static library and link against that.